# Can't show json data (Xamarin.form)

Tags: web-services, xamarin.forms

I think this is because my json gives me an array, but I don't know how it solved, this is what I did. (I'm new at this)

running in Visual Studio 2019 (xamarin.form) with web services but the url is hidden for security, so don't pay attention in that.

---my-json---

```
    {
   "cuentas":[
      {
         "cuenta":"0500",
         "usuario":41
      },
      {
         "cuenta":"0508",         
         "usuario":6
      },
      {
         "cuenta":"0522",
         "usuario":41
      },
      {
         "cuenta":"0532",
         "usuario":41
      },
      null
   ]
}
```

---WSClient.cs---

```
class WSClient
{
   public async Task<T> Post<T>(string url, StringContent c)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, c);


            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);           

        }
 }
```

----Cuenta.cs---

```
public class Cuenta
    {
        public string cuenta { get; set; }
        public int usuario { get; set; }
    }
```

------MainPage.xaml.cs-----

```
private async void BtnCall_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WSClient client = new WSClient();

            string dato = "";

            StringContent content = new StringContent(dato, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var result = await client.Post<Cuenta>("http://www.***", content);

            if (result != null) {

                lblCuenta.Text = result.cuenta;
                lblUsuario.Text = result.cuenta;
            }

        }
```

It doesn't show me anything and it doesn't give me any mistakes... any advice?

( I can see the json in the console if I use WriteLine in "WSClient" )

Comment: please post your Cuenta class

Comment: sorry, there you are

Answer (score 0):

your class should look like this (using json2csharp.com)

```
public class Cuenta
{
    public string cuenta { get; set; }
    public int usuario { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Cuenta> cuentas { get; set; }
}

var result = await client.Post<RootObject>("http://www.***", content);
```

Comment: ok, but in "WSClient.cs" , in this line 

{   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);  }

Give me ->>   I cannot implicitly convert the type "System.Collections.Generic.List <T> in" T "

Comment: use T, not List<T>

Comment: Great !!....one more question, if you don't mind, in Xaml.cs how is that line
-----
lblCuenta.Text = result.cuenta;
-----
I guess I need ListView..If you have any examples, I would appreciate it, and thanks for all. really

Comment: cuenta is a list, so you either need to select single element to display, or use a ListView.  There are numerous examples of LIstView on the Xamarin site